# How do I specify which bluetooth devices can wakeup my iMac?

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake, bluetooth

I've seen many posts regarding bluetooth headphones waking up people's Macbooks, and the solution is usually to uncheck the advanced bluetooth setting which allows for devices to wake up a sleeping computer.

I have an iMac so it's not as simple as opening my laptop to wake it up. I would like to be able to wake it up using my mouse or keyboard but not have it wake up when I open my headphones, turn on my AVR, etc.

Note: I have already attempted to "forget" my AVR from my iMac, but still when I go to turn on my AVR to watch TV my iMac wakes up. I have found the AVR in my com.apple.Bluetooth.plist DeviceCache, but it doesn't seem as though I can edit it. It says I need to find it in Finder, which I've been unable to do. I'm not even sure if deleting the cashe would do it though.